# Creating Relationships in Neo4j Without Recreating Nodes

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm currently working on a project using Neo4j, and I'm facing a challenge related to creating relationships without recreating nodes. Here's a brief overview of the scenario:
want to establish relationships between an existing user, a new post, and multiple categories (already exists).

I aim to establish relationships between an existing user, a newly created post, and multiple pre-existing categories. However, the issue is that, instead of creating relationships only, multiple posts are being generated.

Below is the current Cypher query:

```sql
MATCH (user:User {username: 'your_username'})
MATCH (categories:Category)
WHERE ID(categories) IN [1, 2, 3]

// Create a new post node (you can adjust this part based on your post structure)
CREATE (post:TPost {title: 'Post Title', content: 'Post Content', createdAt: timestamp()})

// Create relationships between the user and the post
CREATE (user)-[:POSTED]->(post)

WITH post, COLLECT(categories) AS categoryList

// this part should create relationships only 
FOREACH (category IN categoryList | 
    CREATE (post)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(category) 
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I want to express my gratitude for your assistance (@Finbar Good). Your solution was quite close to what I needed. However, there was a little issue – instead of creating multiple posts, it was generating new category nodes. To fix this, I implemented a forEach loop, and it resolved the problem.

```sql
MATCH (user:User {username: 'user_name'})
CREATE (post:TPost {title: 'Post Title', content: 'Post Content', createdAt: timestamp()})
CREATE (user)-[:POSTED]->(post)
WITH post
MATCH (categories:Category)
WHERE id(categories) IN [12, 7, 9]
WITH post, collect(categories) as cats
FOREACH (c IN cats | CREATE (post)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(c))

RETURN *
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you, there was a typo in my answer. I've fixed it. By the way, you don't need to collect the categories and then iterate with a FOREACH. Use the fact that `MATCH (categories:Category) WHERE id(categories) IN [12, 7, 9]` generates 3 results that then executes `CREATE (post)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(category)` 3 times. Look at the [documentation on clause composition](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/clause_composition/) to understand how tables of results are passed from clause to clause.

Answer (score 2):

Your second `MATCH` returns 3 `Category` nodes, so the table that is the input to your `CREATE (:TPost)` clause has 3 rows, which means the `CREATE` happens 3 times, creating 3 posts.

Move the `CREATE (:TPost)` to before fetching the 3 `Category` nodes and it will only execute once (assuming there is only one match for the `User`):

```sql
MATCH (user:User {username: 'your_username'})
CREATE (post:TPost {title: 'Post Title', content: 'Post Content', createdAt: timestamp()})
CREATE (user)-[:POSTED]->(post)
WITH post
MATCH (category:Category)
WHERE id(category) IN [1, 2, 3]
CREATE (post)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(category);
```